# Cannot make vim-markdown conceal the formatted text

Tags: neovim, filetype-markdown, conceal, plugin, plugin-vim-markdown

I am quite new to Neovim, just installed some of the important plugins and now I wanted to make it really good for writing Markdown files. I installed **vim-markdown** for that, and followed the documentation in the Git repo.

Even-though I followed the explanations, I wasn't able to make the concealing work.
I am doing a **lua** configuration. I installed the plugin using **packer** and created a **vim-markdown.lua** file in a **.config/nvim/after** directory, where I put my plugin's configuration and keymaps.

I just wrote in there what the **README** in the GIT repo says.
The **vim-markdown.lua** looks like this:

```lua
vim.g.vim_markdown_folding_level = 1 

vim.g.vim_markdown_toc_autofit = 1

vim.o.conceallevel=2 

vim.g.vim_markdown_conceal = 1
```

While installing some other plugin, I came up with this information:
[image: Requisites for concealing]

To clarify:

- The **markdown** plugin is the **preservim/vim-markdown**
- The **font** on my terminal is the *Monospace*
- The **colorscheme** I have in neovim is the **tokyonight**, **dark** version.
- I am using **Terminator** as my terminal

Shouldn't this work? Once I open a **Markdown** file, there is no conceal to be seen...

I appreciate all the feedback. Thank you!

Comment: Do you still have the problem? What if you set the settings using the Neovim commands: ? (i.e.: `let g:vim_markdown_folding_level=1`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Neovim loads lua file from `nvim\after`.

If you want your setting to apply specifically to the `markdown` file type I would create a `markdown.vim` file within: `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin` with the following content:

```
let g:vim_markdown_folding_level=1 

let g:vim_markdown_toc_autofit=1

set conceallevel=2 

let g:vim_markdown_conceal=1
```

Remark: It seems that this version of [vim-markdown](https://github.com/preservim/vim-markdown) has more attention than the Tim Pope's [version](https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown)

Remark: For markdown writing a popular choice seems to be [vimwiki](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki)

Comment: I am not sure that is the problem. All my plugin configs are written in that format. 
And yes, even though the image references other markdown plugin, I am using the one you mentioned now.
But I liked the idea of putting the configuration inside the ftplugin folder

Comment: It is a good idea to use the ftplugin folder. It is exactly the purpose but I strongly doubt that lua file are loaded from there. I advice you to verify the buffer setting by running the corresponding Neovim commands (e.g.: `:set conceallevel?`)

Comment: Yhea, its a really good idea. Btw, is there a way to make it so some of the configs, like **keybindings** only work in **.md** buffers?
It does load, the output is `conceallevel=2`. In the beginning I doubted as well, but with a simple print statement I found that in the startup all the those files are loaded.

Comment: It should probably be the subject of another question but I believe yes.  You can use the special argument `<buffer>` to make a mapping local to a buffer. With an `autocmd` you can set these mapping when the `md` file is loaded into the buffer.

Comment: I appreciate the help!

Comment: The problem is that the big question is still unanswered ahah.